# Understanding Taylor Series from a beginner's perspective

Tags: taylor-expansion

"There's a math analogy here. Take a function, pick a specific point, and dive in. You can pull out enough data from a single point to rebuild the entire function. Whoa. It's like remaking a movie from a single frame.

The Taylor Series discovers the "math DNA" behind a function and lets us rebuild it from a single data point. Let's see how it works." Source: https://betterexplained.com/articles/taylor-series/

While functions like y=x^2 appears plausible for the above statements, what about a function say sketched by me using a pen without following any fixed pattern. How can one predict value of say f(5) from f(1)!

Comment: this is terrible writing and it would be better to look at a different source on Taylor series.

Comment: Taylor series does not work for every function. There is a class of functions called *analytic* functions, for which it works. The catch is that, even though those are rare (of sorts) among functions, *almost all* functions you normally have to deal with (starting with polynomials, exponential, trigonometric etc., including those complicated functions defined via integrals or infinite sums, e.g. $\Gamma$-function or Riemann $\zeta$-function - are analytic (wherever they are defined, and "even further" - there is a thing called "analytic continuation").

Comment: @GrafZahl It is not enough that the function is smooth. It needs to be analytic.

Comment: You are not just looking at $f(1)$ but also $f'(1),f''(1),\ldots$ and assuming it is an  analytic function

Comment: As for the quality of writing, whether (for an introductory / "give me the intuition" text) one prefers rigorous but slightly boring, or inspiring but slightly(?) misleading text is down to anyone's preference. I personally hope this text will inspire the OP to learn more. (At which point, hope they do find something more rigorous, if serious about studying Taylor series, of course!)

Comment: I agree with Matthew. But such a style is not only typical for math articles that are "written for beginners" , articles about astronomy (not necessarily for beginners) have a very similar style. This surely (unfortunately) will increase the edition, but is not the way it should be taught.

Comment: @GrafZahl No(!), actually $C^\infty$ is not nearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you know f(1) you will not know f(5) for any function. If you draw a function you may be able to see the tangent at x=1 but not more so you know f'(1) this gives you only a rough guess how the function will continue for points very near to x=1, for more information you need all the other derivatives which you can not see in your drawing, so you will noch be able to find a Taylor series of your function. You have to use other means to find a good approximation for your drawn curve. This is called  approximation or interpolation  by polygons. You have to use more points on your curve.
for a better understanding of Taylor approximation, consider first Polynomials. if you know one point of a straight line an its slope i.e. derivative , you know the whole line.
For a second degree polynomial  you need f, f' and f'' at one point and you know it completely, for third order you need also f''' to know it completely and so on. This gives a good impression that knowing many derivatives gives you a good approximation of a function . If you know only some you get a very good approximation in the neighborhood of the known point, but not far of, like the drawing of sin(x) in your linked article shows.